# C# Expression to compare values like LINQtoSQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda

I cannot use LinqToSql in my project so I'm implementing something like that. I have an object where I need to compare values :

```
obj.Where(w=> w.Name == "NAME");
```

Method Where looks like this :

```
Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
```

I already know how to get a property name but I nees to ge following information from the expression:

1. Operator used in expression (==, >=, <=)
2. Value to which I'm comparing original value

So finally I can build an SQL select query.

**EXAMPLE**

```
obj.Where(w=> w.Name == "NAME");
```

returns

```
WHERE Name = 'NAME'
```

Thanks for your help,
B.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse expression tree, for example using a [visitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor(v=vs.110).aspx) like in [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521(v=vs.90).aspx). But before developing custom SQL query generator I'd definitely  consider using an existing one - the task is really complicated. [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx), for example.

Comment: That didn't provide me any examples